# Query string from a link not passed into mobile apps like Salesforce and SharePoint

Tags: android, ios, sharepoint, salesforce, query-string

I generate these link to Salesforce, SharePoint, etc. platforms.

e.g. [https://client.lightning.force.com/page?query=string\](https://client.lightning.force.com/page?query=string%5C)
e.g. https://client.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/page?query=string

These links are usually shared via media like email, Teams, Slack, etc.

If such a link is clicked on a mobile device, it gets opened in the device's default browser temporarily and successfully redirects to the appropriate mobile app. That's great! HOWEVER, the problem is that the `?query=string` part is not passed into the mobile app. (I think it works in some Android apps, but overall the behavior is not consistent.)

**Problem Summary**: Query string information is lost when an external link gets redirected to the mobile app. Apps I am talking about are Salesforce and SharePoint, on both iOS and Android OS.

**Question**: This looks like a restriction by iOS/Android OS or maybe Salesforce/SharePoint apps? Anyway, is this solvable?

**What I have tried**:

- Storing the query string values in client-side storages, like cookies, localstorage, etc. In my experience, these storages are not shared between the browser and the mobile apps. Hence, I cannot read these values.
- A "server-side hack" by creating an intermediate link that stores on the server which 'sub route' to load once the mobile app loads, but that only works if I can already identify that user from the link. It will not work for anonymous links, obviously.